# Set LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly

Tags: environment-variables, matlab, paths, boost

I am using Docker with image of Ubuntu 16.04. I am using this docker to run:

- Import C++ classes in python with the help of boost.python
- Import matlab's python package in python with the help Matlab Runtime (MCR).

Before I have installed MCR in the docker, I have installed boost using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libboost-all-dev
```

and I was able to wrap C++ classes and call them in python. Then I have installed MCR and one of the requirement is to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to Matlab's library.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

It worked, I was able to run matlab's python package in python but testing the C++ classes wrappers failed due to change of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example, I get the following error when I try to import C++ class in python:

```
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0: undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt
```

If I unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` C++ import works but MCR fails. So the question what `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be in order to run both C++ classes and Matlab's python package successfully?

I have tried to add path to boost libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but didn't work, so the env value would be:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64
```

**EDIT**

the dependencies of C++ library file before setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcee0dc000)
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007f9d69e59000)
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 (0x00007f9d69c09000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f9d698fe000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9d695fd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9d693e7000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d6903c000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9d68e34000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f9d68c0b000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f9d689f0000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9d687d3000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d685cf000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007f9d683cc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d6a6c3000)
```

After setting `the LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc42e9b000)
    libpython3.4m.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.4m.so.1.0 (0x00007fad9635b000)
    libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py34.so.1.55.0 (0x00007fad9610b000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fad95d8a000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fad95a89000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fad95873000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fad954c8000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fad952c0000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007fad95095000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fad94e7a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fad94c5d000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fad94a59000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fad94856000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fad96bc5000)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way it worked for me is by defining `LD_PRELOAD` and point it to system library. So my current environment would be:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
```

So in docker, I have created a `.matlab` file that contains the mentioned env variables. Then, in dockerfile I added the following:

```
services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - shared_upload_tmp:/app_temp
      - media:/app/computation_server/media
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
      - ./.envs/.production/.matlab
    ports:
      - "8800:8000"
    command: /start
```

Answer (score 7):

This [Stack Exchange Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428910/how-to-set-the-environmental-variable-ld-library-path-in-linux) has various ways of setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` the top voted answer suggests this is the best way:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/randomLibs.conf
```

inside the file you are supposed to write the complete path to the directory that contains all the libraries that you wish to add to the system, for example

```
/home/linux/myLocalLibs
```

remember to add only the path to the dir, not the full path for the file, all the libs inside that path will be automatically indexed.

Save and run `sudo ldconfig` to update the system with this libs.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to export the LD_LIBRARY_PATH? can't you just preface the matlab call with it, e.g.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/runtime/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/bin/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/sys/os/glnxa64:/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v94/extern/bin/glnxa64 /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/...
```

(I do not exactly know what the executable is called like)

You could put that in a little skript

Secondly, it could be possible to change the rpath of the executable or some library, so it looks at the correct place directly. I use patchelf for this

```
patchelf --set-rpath
```

Since there are multiple paths involved it could get a bit tricky, though

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the preface didn't work with me.. I am trying to do the patchelf but it seems complicated. And in the future I might have many C++ classes.. wouldn't this mean that I will need to do it for all of them?

Comment: you would have to do this for every executable / shared library. But If you compile them yourself you must be able to set this at compile time ( or link time to be precise)